# Can't understand which partition is unallocated space during an Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, installation, ubuntu-12.04

This might seem a really stupid question. I have windows 8 on my laptop. I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside it. My hard drive is supposed to have 20 GB unallocated space on it to install Ubuntu. Now I am in the installation phase. And I can't seem to find it.

There is a window which says installation type. There are options like `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda3` etc. But I can't seem to understand which one to select.

Answer (score 0):

"Unallocated space" isn't a partition; it's the unused space *between* partitions. It won't have a device name until you create one or more partitions in that space.